# Mysql order by percent of two values sum

Tags: mysql

So I need to order by percent counted from two values of one field where data is stored in JSON.

The field name where values are stored named `program_invested_details` and for example value is:

`{"invested":"120.00","received":"1.08"}`

I need that `$query` would be `(received * 100 / invested)` from that field

```
SELECT *, ($query) AS PERRCENT_TOTAL 
FROM programs_list 
WHERE program_add_status = 4 AND program_status = 1 ORDER BY PERRCENT_TOTAL DESC
```

how does it possible to make?

Answer (score 1):

By default MySQL does not have any ability to parse a JSON string.

One option would be to use an extension such as `common_schema` which would add the ability to parse JSON and extract fields (see [`get_option`](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/get_option.html)).  I am not sure of the performance hit you would take with this extension.

Another option would be to query all the data and parse the JSON in your client program.  Once again, there would be significant performance impact if there is a lot of data.

Comment: It looks like great idea with get_option. I tried it but it seems that there is an error. What could be wrong with this query? `SELECT *, ((get_option("program_invested_details", "received") * 100) / get_option("program_invested_details", "invested")) AS PERRCENT_TOTAL FROM programs_list WHERE program_add_status = 4 AND program_status = 1 ORDER BY PERRCENT_TOTAL DESC`

Comment: Do you have the [`common_schema`](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) extension installed?  It does not come installed by default.

Comment: It looks like the client version is lower then required (5.1 required, 5.0.10 have..) but the website have to work on shared host so I don't think they will install new client only for me

Comment: It actually is a server side extension, so it would have to be installed on the server.  Being a shared host it is highly doubtful they would install it.